# Magento upgrade 2.3.5

Tags: magento2.3, upgrade, magento-upgrade

Previously i was using Magento 2.3.4 and upgraded to 2.3.5 using command line

I now see that there is also a 2.3.5-p1.

When 2.3.6 comes out later this month do i go straight from 2.3.5 to 2.3.6 or do i need to install 2.3.5-p1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade direct to version 2.3.6.

Comment: Thank you, with 2.4 now available next month, how long are updates provided for 2.3?

Comment: I don't know if that has been announced yet, with 2.2 updates were available for about 12 months before it went end of life. I expect 2.3 will be EOL sometime towards the end of next year.

Comment: Hi Paj, magento has now released 2.3.5-p2 do i upgrade direct to this? or Upgrade to p1 then p2?

Comment: As long as your server meets all the requirements for a new release you can always upgrade straight to the latest version. Always test upgrades first on your dev environment.

Comment: always check the release notes for patch versions for example for 2.3.5.p2 the release notes state "You must deploy Magento 2.3.5 before applying this patch."